# several ordenation needs in the same request

Tags: random, pagination, solr, request

i have a doubt about solr possibilities.  i need to do a request with special issues:

i need first: promoted records with all the terms typed by the user (ordered randomly).
second: promoted records with any term typed by the user (ordered randomly).
third: promoted records found by the stemming search (ordered randomly).
fourth: promoted records found by the phonetic search (randomly).
fifth: free records ordered alphabeticly (having all or any term typed by the user).

these results need to be paginated.

is it possible to do it in the same request?

Answer (score 0):

After finding out that random ordering is support in solr via:

```
<fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" />
<field name="random" type="random" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

those queries will be possible but NOT in one query

Although one could use the facet and facet.query feature, but this only returns the count ... not the docs.

I would setup a separate advertising index instead of the normal way to implement 'advertising' with the [elevation component](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent)

> promoted records with all the terms typed by the user (ordered randomly)

a simple AND query against the advertising index

> promoted records with any term typed by the user (ordered randomly)

a simple OR query against the advertising index

> promoted records found by the stemming search (ordered randomly).

normal search (with stemming) in the advertisment index.

> promoted records found by the phonetic search (randomly).

you'll need to transform the query and the terms via your own phonetic transformation to do that. so you'll have a special field phonetic_text and you'll need to query this via

q=phonetic_text:"U R G8" (which means: you are great ;-))

> free records ordered alphabeticly (having all or any term typed by the user).

again normal search via "AND" or "OR" with the sort parameter